How to construct a collection of magic triples?
This problem was posted three days ago.

In a deck of 81 cards (all different from each other), it is said that
given any two cards, there is exactly one card that forms a "magic"
triple with them. How many magic triples are there?

I'm trying to find such collection of magic triples.
Let's try a simpler problem with $6$ card instead of $81$. Let's say those cards are $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}.$
According to lulu's answer, there should be ${6 \choose 2}/3 = 5$ magic triples.
But I can't figure out what are the 5 magic triples. Here is a collection I can find
$$\{1,2,3\},\{1,4,5\},\{2,4,6\},\{3,5,6\}$$
I can't seem to find the fifth magic triple. It should be something like $\{1,6,...\}$ but other cards already been used.
What did I miss?
Here are my question:

Does the number $81$ has something special that $6$ doesn't have?
If the answer to (1) is no, is there an algorithm to form a collection of magic triples? Since if someone started with $\{1,2,3\}$ then $\{4,5,6\}$ they will only get two magic triples and, of course, it doesn't satisfty the problem.


lulu's answer does not guarantee that there is a collection of magic triples for every deck size $N$. There are such collections, though, for powers $N = 3^m$ and $N = 7$. The former includes the case $N = 81$, which is the setting of the card game Set.

I wrote an answer to this question, but this question was deleted before I finished. I wrote a question and posted my answer there before this question was undeleted: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4914067/for-which-n-does-a-deck-of-n-cards-admit-a-collection-of-magic-triples/4914068
