For which $N$ does a deck of $N$ cards admit a collection of "magic triples"?
This self-answered question was asked to give a place to post an answer to a question of general interest that was deleted after the answer was mostly composed. Of course, other answers are also welcome.
Per this combinatorics question, say that a deck of $N$ cards admits a collection of "magic triples" if for any $2$ distinct cards in the deck there is a unique third card that forms a "magic triple" with them. More precisely, we say that a set $X$ of $N$ (distinct) cards admits a collection of magic triples if there is a set $\mathcal{T} \subset \mathcal{P}(X)$ such that

every element of $\mathcal T$ has $3$ elements, and
for any distinct elements $x, y \in X$, there is a unique set $T \in \mathcal T$ such that both $x \in T$ and $y \in T$.

We call the elements of $\mathcal T$ themselves magic triples.
For which $N > 0$ does a deck of $N$ cards admit magic triples?

We can quickly deduce some restrictions on $N$. If a deck of $N$ cards admits a collection of magic triples, then the number of triples, $\frac13 {N \choose 2} = \frac16 N (N - 1)$ (see this answer to the linked question), is an integer, so $N \equiv 0, 1 \pmod 3$. Moreover, each card is a member of exactly $\frac3N \cdot \frac13 {N \choose 2} = \frac{1}{2} (N - 1)$ triples, so $N$ must be odd. Combining these observations gives that $N \equiv 1, 3 \pmod 6$.
In the language of combinatorial designs, we can regard a deck of $N$ cards with a collection of magic triples as a Steiner triple system of order $N$. Skolem showed in 1958 (see the citation at the end of this answer) that in fact $N \equiv 1, 3 \pmod 6$ is also a sufficient condition for existence and moreover gave a mostly explicit construction too long to reproduce here:
$$\boxed{\textrm{A deck of $N > 0$ cards admits a collection of magic triples iff $N \equiv 1, 3 \pmod 6$.}}$$
There are a few interesting families of examples.
Example ($N = 3^m$: Affine spaces over $\Bbb F_3$) Identify the cards with the points in the vector space $\Bbb F_3^m$ of $m$-tuples of elements of $\Bbb F_3 = \{0, 1, 2\}$, and declare that $3$ distinct points (cards) form a magic triple if they are the three points on line, that is, if their sum is $\bf 0$. So, given distinct points ${\bf a}, {\bf b} \in \Bbb F_3^m$, the third point on the line is $-{\bf a} - {\bf b}$. If you prefer to number the cards by consecutive integers $0, 1, \ldots, 3^m - 2, 3^m - 1$, just interpret the points $(a_1, \ldots, a_m)$ as the integer $(\overline{a_1 \cdots a_m})_3$ written in base $3$.
Such a deck has $\frac12 3^{m - 1} (3^m - 1)$ magic triples, and each card is part of $\frac12 (3^m - 1)$ triples.
The case $m = 2$ gives a deck of $9$ cards and $12$ triples. For convenience write the pair $(a_1, a_2)$ as $a_1 a_2$ and interpret the latter as the base-$3$ representation $(\overline{a_1 a_2})_3$ of an integer. This result is a collection of magic triples on the deck $\{0, \ldots, 8\}$:
\begin{align}
(0, 1, 2), \quad (0, 3, 6), \quad (0, 4, 8), \quad (0, 5, 7), \\
(1, 3, 8), \quad (1, 4, 7), \quad (1, 5, 6), \quad (2, 3, 7), \\
(2, 4, 6), \quad (2, 5, 8), \quad (3, 4, 5), \quad (6, 7, 8) .
\end{align}
The case $N = 81$ ($m = 4$) has been developed into a card game, Set, wherein "magic triples" are called "sets".
Example ($N = 2^{r + 1} - 1$: Projective spaces over $\Bbb F_2$) The condition that each pair of distinct cards determine a magic triple is reminiscent of the axiom of projective geometry that each pair of points determine a line. We can thus identify a deck of cards with the points of a projective space over a field and magic triples with lines, provided that each line has exactly $3$ points on it. This is the case exactly if the underlying field is the field $\Bbb F_2 = \{0, 1\}$ of $2$ elements. The projective space $\operatorname{PG}(r, 2)$ of dimension $r$ over $\Bbb F_2$ has $2^{r + 1} - 1$ cards (points), which we can denote by $[a_1 : \cdots : a_{r + 1}]$, $a_1, \ldots, a_{r + 1} \in \Bbb F_2$ (with not all $a_i$ equal to $0$), hence $\frac13 (2^{r + 1} - 1) (2^r - 1)$ magic triples (lines).

The case $r = 2$ gives the Fano plane, the smallest projective plane, which we can regard as a deck of $7$ cards and $7$ magic triples, where each card is a part of $3$ triples. For convenience denote $[a_1 : a_2 : a_3]$ by $a_1 a_2 a_3$, and interpret the latter expressions as integers $(\overline{a_1 a_2 a_3})_2$ written in base $2$. Then, a collection of magic triples for the deck $\{1, \ldots, 7\}$ is:
$$(1, 2, 3), \quad 
  (1, 4, 5), \quad 
  (1, 6, 7), \quad 
  (2, 4, 6), \quad 
  (2, 5, 7), \quad 
  (3, 4, 7), \quad 
  (3, 5, 6) .$$

The case $r = 3$ gives $\operatorname{PG}(3, 2)$, which we can regard as a deck of $15$ cards and $35$ magic triples, where each card is a part of $7$ triples. This case is connected with Kirkman's Schoolgirl Problem.


For $N = 13$, applying Skolem's construction for $N \equiv 1 \pmod 6$ with $(a_1, b_1, a_2, b_2) = (1, 2, 3, 5)$ gives a deck $\{0, \ldots, 12\}$ with triples
$$(x, x + 1, x + 4) \qquad \textrm{and} \qquad (x, x + 2, x + 7), \qquad x = 0, \ldots, 12 ,$$
where the values are regarded modulo $13$.
For $N = 1, 3, 7, 9$, there is a single collection of magic triples for a deck of $N$ cards, up to isomorphism (essentially, relabeling of cards), and each is a special case of one (or both) of the above two examples. For $N \geq 13$, $N \equiv 1, 3 \pmod 6$, there is more than one collection of magic triples on a deck of $N$ cards up to isomorphism. The number of isomorphism types of collections of magic triples for a deck of size $N$ is the content of the sequence OEIS A030129.

Skolem, T. (1958). "Some Remarks on the Triple Systems of Steiner". Mathematica Scandinavica 6, 273–280. https://doi.org/10.7146/math.scand.a-10551

